# Using method add all numbers of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

Am I doing it right? I am trying to add each number of this 2 dimensional array and display the total. I think I am on the right track but well I am stuck if anyone could help me I be very thankful.

```
    int[,] A = new int[3, 4] 
    { 
        { 4, -5, 12, -2},
        { -9, 15, 19, 6},
        { 18, -33, -1, 7}
    };
      private void TotArray(int[,] array) 
      {
          int sum = 0;
          int rows = array.GetLength(0);
          int cols = array.GetLength(1);
          for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
              {
                  sum += A[i, j];
              }
          }
       }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TotArray(A);
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @MattBurland The problem is it aint displaying nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the sum at the end:

```
int[,] A = new int[3, 4] 
{ 
    { 4, -5, 12, -2},
    { -9, 15, 19, 6},
    { 18, -33, -1, 7}
};
  private void TotArray(int[,] array) 
  {
      int sum = 0;
      int rows = array.GetLength(0);
      int cols = array.GetLength(1);
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
          {
              sum += A[i, j];
          }
      }
      MessageBox.Show("The sum of the array is " + sum.ToString() + "."); //Show the sum
   }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TotArray(A);
}
```

Comment: If I do that I get a error at TotArray saying it cannot return the value

Answer (score 3):

You are ignoring the `sum` variable, you should return it from your method.other than that your method looks fine.Also remember you can always use `LINQ` for that kind of operations:

```
var sum = A.OfType<int>().Sum();
```